# Group array by name in Jquery and display as list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, grouping

I have an array like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "cityname": "Newyork",
  "countryname": "USA"
},
{
  "cityname": "amsterdam",
  "countryname": "Netherland"
},{
  "cityname": "Washington",
  "countryname": "USA"
},{
  "cityname": "London",
  "countryname": "UK"
},{
  "cityname": "Los Angeles",
  "countryname": "USA"
},{
  "cityname": "Assen",
  "countryname": "Netherland"
},
,{
  "cityname": "Liverpool",
  "countryname": "UK"
},
,{
  "cityname": "chicago",
  "countryname": "USA"
},
{
  "cityname": "New Delhi",
  "countryname": "India"
},
]
}
```

My aim is to list all cities under corresponding countries.In this array, there are same country names. I want to group this array by countryname in jquery. And want to list countries and cities like this.

```
<label>USA</label>
<ul>
<li>Newyork</li>
<li>Washington</li>
<li>Chikago</li>
<li>Los Angeles</li>
</ul>

<label>UK</label>
<ul>
<li>London</li>
<li>Liverpool</li>
</ul>

<label>Netherland</label>
<ul>
<li>Amsterdam</li>
<li>Assen</li>
</ul>

<label>India</label>
<ul>
<li>New Delhi</li>
</ul>
```

So how can I do this in a better way in jquery without using any plugin? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need or want JQuery for Array manipulation in the first place?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing or tutorial service. The objective is for you to show what you have tried and people help fix **your code**

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with a bit of logic like this

```
$(data).each(function(){
if($('#'+this.countryname).length)
{
  $('#'+this.countryname).append('<li>'+this.cityname+'</li>')
}
else
 {
$('#bodyDiv').append('<label>'+this.countryname+'</label><ul id="'+this.countryname+'"></ul>')
$('#'+this.countryname).append('<li>'+this.cityname+'</li>')
}
})
```

here #bodyDiv is the id of the div element where you want to populate ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, which you can [see in action on JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6gn4t09y/).

```
data.forEach(function(datum) {
  let countryList = $('[data-countryname='+datum.countryname+']');
  if(countryList.length === 0) {
    let newLabel = document.createElement('label');
    let newList = document.createElement('ul');
    $(newLabel).html(datum.countryname);
    $(newList).attr('data-countryname',datum.countryname);
    $('body').append(newLabel);
    $('body').append(newList);
    countryList = newList;
  }
  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  $(newListItem).html(datum.cityname);
  countryList.append(newListItem);
})
```